# avoid nested loop when adding elements to iterated list

Tags: python, python-3.9

I try to avoid nested loops in Python. In general, I manage to do so by using some `itertools` utility, the `zip` function, etc. However, there is still one case for which I have not been able to eliminate the classic nested loop structure: the case where, while iterating through a list, you want to append elements to that same list, and you want those elements to be part of the loop.

Here is an example:

```
a = [1,5,21]

for i1, val1 in enumerate(a):
  for i2 in range(i1+1, len(a)):
    val2 = a[i2]
    if (val1+val2)%3==0 and abs(val1-val2)<30:
      a.append(val1+val2)
    
print("final", a) #[1, 5, 21, 6, 27, 33, 60, 93]
```

Can someone help me rewrite this without using a nested loop?

Comment: I'd say you can't and that isn't a problem at all, sometimes you need 2 nested loops, sometimes 3, that' ok

Comment: Why do you avoid nested loops? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a while loop.

```
expected = [1, 5, 21, 6, 27, 33, 60, 93]
a = [1,5,21]

val1, val2 = a[0], a[1]
idx = 0
while abs(val1-val2) < 30: 
    if (val1 + val2) % 3 == 0:
        a.append(val1+val2)
    idx += 1
    val1, val2 = a[idx], a[idx+1]
a == expected # True
```

Comment: This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason, you are not going with nested loop approach?

However, under the assumption you want to try something apart from loop. I’ve created similar program using recursion. Hope this helps!

```
def fn_recur(a,i1,i2):
    val1 = a[i1]
    val2 = a[i2]
    if (val1+val2)%3 == 0 and abs(val1-val2) < 30:
      a.append(val1+val2)
    if(i2+1 < 3):
        i2 = i2+1
    elif(i1+2 < len(a)):
        i1 = i1+1
        i2 = i1+1
    else:
        print(a)
        return a
    fn_recur(a,i1,i2)
fn_recur([1,5,21],0,1)
#output [1, 5, 21, 6, 27, 33, 60, 93]
```